# How can I set outlook web app to send from/send as an email alias?

Tags: email, alias, outlook-web-access

I have an email account I access through the outlook web app and I have an email forwarder. I want to be able to send messages appearing as from the email forwarder. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools and choose Options
Go to the Delegates Tab and click Add
Select the user who wish to grant access to and click Add and then Ok

Or, on the reply window, click on Options and select From.

Answer (score -1):

U log using personal imap.mail domain. That allows your incoming mail.  And smtp.mail allows outgoing mail. I especially works for Microsoft exchange accounts and live .com accounts. 
When you log in to outlook, choose manual setup. As you continue follow the instructions.